Compatibility and Differences Between i18next-http-backend and i18next-resources-to-backend in react-i18next
I’m using react-i18next in my project and I’m considering using both i18next-http-backend and i18next-resources-to-backend libraries. Can these two libraries be used together, and what are the main differences between them? I’m not entirely clear on how they differ in their functionality and best use cases.

This plugin use for same purpose - provide dictionaries by language and namespace. i18next-http-backend implements loading dictionaries via http. i18next-resources-to-backend leaves the method of obtaining the dictionary to your discretion. You can use them together using i18next-chained-backend.
